# Is there any way to disable frequent-tag highlighting?

Tags: support, tags

Apparently I have been frequently visiting questions that have an 'ai' tag. Now questions with an 'ai' tag appear highlighted in yellow. **Is there any way to disable this?**

I tried going to 'set tag preferences' to disable it, but there is no option to do so. In fact the 'ai' tag does not even appear there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Why is Stack Overflow suddenly orange (#FFEFC6)?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72587/why-is-stack-overflow-suddenly-orange/72593#72593)

There doesn't seem to be an option to disable it outright, but a work around seems to be to use the favorite/ignored tag system in some capacity.  So, in theory, if you mark a tag you don't like as ignored it'll remove all that stuff.

Comment: Or put a nonsense tag in.  I'm partial to [unicorn]. (:

Comment: [unicorn] it is.

Comment: Actually I recommend giving the favorite system a legitimate shot; I really like it myself, especially on the more popular sites (like Stack Overflow) where you would otherwise be overwhelmed by all the questions there.

Comment: I agree with Ricket. It sometimes seems to know me better than I know myself.